# how do you integrate 2 different shiny apps in one

Tags: r, shiny

I have two shiny apps with ui and server compoents. I need to create one app and be able to open the each application with tabs. Clicking on one tab will bring the app.

first app is like this:

```
ui <- pageWithSidebar(....)
server <- function(input, output,session) {....}
```

second app is something like this:

```
 shinyUI(....)
server <- function(input, output, session) {.....}
```

How could I create one app and refer to these apps from tabs within one app?

Comment: perhaps try the `shinydashboard` package to make one webpage with multiple items?

Comment: [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69477973/9841389) you can find a related answer.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, this could be achieved in two ways.

1. Simple shiny app:

You can create tabs using `tabPanel(title, ...)` function and then wrapping all the `tabPanel()`s inside a `tabsetPanel()` function.

So, in your case you can put all the UI elements of your first app inside the first `tabPanel('unique_title')` and so on.

This will help you create multiple independently viewable sections.

You can refer these two links to know more 
http://shiny.rstudio.com/reference/shiny/latest/tabPanel.html

2. As @Michal suggested, using `shinydashboard`:

`shinydashnoard` is another package that you will have to install in order to use this feature of shiny. It basically has a predefined structure with a header, a sidebar and a body.

The basic structure is shown below:

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)

ui <- dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(),
  dashbaordSidebar(),
  dashboardBody()
)

server <- function(input,output,server){...}
```

Normally, `dashboardSidebar()` is used for navigation. However, it can contain `menuItem()` that behave like tabs in a `tabPanel()`.

For your case, you can add multiple `menuItem()`s inside `sidebarMenu()` as shown below

## Updated Code

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)

ui <- dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(),
  dashboardSidebar(
    sidebarMenu(
      menuItem("first_app", tabName = "first_app"),
      menuItem("second_app", tabName = "second_app")
    )
  ),
  dashboardBody(
    tabItems(
      tabItem(tabName = "first_app",
              h2("First App Content")
      ),
      tabItem(tabName = "second_app",
              h2("Second App Content"))
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input,output,server){}

shinyApp(ui,server)
```

This will create a basic dashboard page with 2 menu items.

You can also refer to link below to know more about the shinydashboard structure
https://rstudio.github.io/shinydashboard/structure.html

I hope this helps :)

Comment: I like to use tabPanel, do you know of any apps that use this feature?

Comment: The example in the link below demonstrates the tabset and tabpanel widgets
http://shiny.rstudio.com/gallery/tabsets.html

Comment: using library(shinydasbboard), how would I include my apps withing menuItem you have mentioned?

Comment: I've updated the code to give you an idea on how you can add the contents of your apps using `menuItem()`