# How can I combine two shiny apps?

Tags: r, shiny, shiny-server, shinyapps

I have 2 different Shinnyapps in 2 different directories. And let's assume Shinyapp1's [UI and server](https://shiny.rstudio.com/gallery/option-groups-for-server-side-selectize.html) and Shinnyapp2's [UI and server](https://shiny.rstudio.com/gallery/creating-a-ui-from-a-loop.html) as given. How can I create 1 Shinyapp by combining these 2 different apps without rewriting the code? or if you know any GitHub example for this? Many thanks in advance.

```
 library(shiny)

ui <- navbarPage("Combine 2 Shinyapps",
           tabPanel("Shinyapp1"),
           tabPanel("Shinyapp2")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) { 
}
shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: Can use `iframe` maybe https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33020558/embed-iframe-inside-shiny-app/33021018#33021018

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36291489/how-do-you-integrate-2-different-shiny-apps-in-one also some ideas here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59592687/how-to-separate-out-tabs-into-their-own-script-in-a-shiny-app

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example using iframes (an approach I already mentioned in your [duplicated earlier question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69447802/how-to-combine-2-shinyapps#comment122777881_69447802)).

In the global part im writing two dummy app.R files which are started in a seperate R process via `callr::r_bg`:

```
library(shiny)
library(callr)

makeDir <- function(dir){
  if(!dir.exists(dir)){
    dir.create(dir, recursive = TRUE)
  }}

lapply(c("app1", "app2"), makeDir)

writeLines(text = 'ui <- fluidPage(p("App 1 content"), 
sliderInput("obs", "Number of observations:",
    min = 0, max = 1000, value = 500
  ))
server <- function(input, output, session) {}
shinyApp(ui, server)', con = "app1/app.R")

writeLines(text = 'ui <- fluidPage(p("App 2 content"),
sliderInput("obs", "Number of observations:",
    min = 0, max = 100, value = 50
  ))
server <- function(input, output, session) {}
shinyApp(ui, server)', con = "app2/app.R")

r_bg(function(){
  shiny::runApp(
  appDir = "app1",
  port = 3939,
  launch.browser = FALSE,
  host = "127.0.0.1"
)}, supervise = TRUE)

r_bg(function(){
  shiny::runApp(
  appDir = "app2",
  port = 4040,
  launch.browser = FALSE,
  host = "127.0.0.1"
)}, supervise = TRUE)


ui <- navbarPage("Combine 2 Shinyapps",
                 tabPanel("Shinyapp1", tags$iframe(src="http://127.0.0.1:3939/", height="900vh", width="100%", frameborder="0", scrolling="yes")),
                 tabPanel("Shinyapp2", tags$iframe(src="http://127.0.0.1:4040/", height="900vh", width="100%", frameborder="0", scrolling="yes"))
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
}

mainApp <- shinyApp(ui, server)

runApp(mainApp)
```

**Another (better) approach** would be to wrap both apps in separate [modules](https://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/modules.html) with their own name space. This is less computationally intensive (a single R process instead of 3) but it would require to rearrange the code (which is not desired by OP: `without rewriting the code`).

Comment: I second the remark about modules that can be a good solution for reusing code and make multiple apps/ combine them